# python: convert .mp4 file to 4d numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, video

I have a video formatted as a .mp4 that I would like to convert to and from a numpy array.  For now, I just want the picture, not the audio.  The array should be something like this: 4-dimensional numpy array, making up each frame, row, pixel, rgb values.  This is just a likely intermediate stage to try to clarify my question.  Ultimately however, each individual frame can be flattened so that the array is only 2-dimensional: frame, rgb.  how can I convert a .mp4 to my specified array format, and then back to a .mp4?

Comment: btw, If you know of a better format than .mp4, I might be able to convert it to that.

Comment: That is not that hard with the right tools, but are you aware about the memory-consumption? E.g. 10 min full-hd at 25fps -> 45 GB. Some other remarks: mp4 is a container not a codec. And depending on the codec, you will lose information. Example: h264 -> color-transformation to RGB is imperfect.

Comment: Going on what @sascha said, you might want to process just one frame a time.

Comment: In a more classic and professional setting, i would recommend the concept of frameserving, but not sure if that's something which can apply in your case. Sticking with python vapoursynth, or else avisynth are two common examples. Those are built for the use-case of doing something on video/audio without keeping full uncompressed copies and try to keep compatible with some encoder or other pipeline-components (an encoder at the end does not know that it's not a real file as input; not simple as an encoder typically needs many frames to some decision for the current one).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  These are valid concerns that I will take into consideration.  In light of this, it would be helpful if I accessed the video in parts (i.e. only worked with about 10 seconds at a time).  But right now, I just need a working solution, even if it is terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
import skvideo.io
video_4d_array = skvideo.io.vread('sample.mp4')
# Insert your transformations here
skvideo.io.vwrite('sample.mp4', video_4d_array)
```